# How to get all files recursively by extension using filepath.Glob()?

Tags: go, glob

I am trying to parse all the files with an extension with the text/template parser, which uses the `filepath.Glob()` function under the hood to match files.

```golang
package main 

//go:embed templates
var templates embed.FS

func main() {
  folder, _ := fs.Sub(t, "templates")
  tpl, err := template.ParseFS(folder, "**/*.gohtml")
  // ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't a specification defining the behaviour of glob patterns, however this pattern in Node.js will match all files in a directory with the `.gohtml` extension.

It doesn't seem to match all files in Go, however manually adding folders selects the correct files.

```golang
tpl, err := template.ParseFS(folder, "*.gohtml", "partials/*.gohtml")
```

I tried looking at the [documentation on the Go website](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Glob) but struggled to find resources on the pattern matching rules.

I'm hoping it's as simple as getting the right variation of `*`s, `/`s and I just haven't found it

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath@go1.19.5#Match